# Listing users with their last article with one SQL request on Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

```py
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Article(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I need to list all users with their last article. How can I get them with **one database request**?

```py
# Something like:
{% for user in users %}:
    {{ user.full_name }}: {{ user.last_message }}
{% endfor %}
```

- *John Doe: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.*
- *Jake Carr: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.*
- *Malcolm Gordon: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.*
- *Ingredia Ameter: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.*

Comment: How do you sort the articles? Do you have a datefield somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is your query:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery


latest = Article.objects.filter(
    user=OuterRef('pk')
).order_by('-created_at')

users = User.objects.annotate(
    last_message=Subquery(latest.values("content")[:1])
)

for user in users:
    print(user.username, user.last_message)
```

it give you users with their last **Articles**.

**P.s:** it will execute only one query.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also found this when I research `Subquery` and `OuterRef` after read your answer: [Django Subquery() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions)

Comment: Glad it helped.